# I have downloaded a map of a small region in .osm format . But as a newbie I dont have any idea how to access it using any programming language

Tags: geospatial, uses-of-open-data, city

I need this map data to provide the location of nearest business facilities like restaurant to the user .  But I don't know how to access it . And it will be of great help if you can provide me any link /tutorial /suggestion to do this using any programming language (preferably using Python )

Comment: This is a very open-ended question and may get closed. https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/OSM is what I've done, mostly in Perl. Feel free to contact me directly (see my profile) and I can try to help.